# NoSQL in a single machine

Tags: nosql, relational-database, data-warehouse, distributed-system

As part of my university curriculum I ended up with a real project which consists in helping a company shifting from their relational data warehouse into a NoSQL data warehouse. The thing is that what they are looking for is better performance in large jobs but so far they have used a single machine and if they indeed migrate to NoSQL they still wish to keep using a single machine for cost reasons.

As far as I know the whole point of NoSQL is to run it in a large distributed system of several machines. So I don't see the point of this migration, specially since I am pretty sure (but not entirely) that if they do install NoSQL, they will probably end having even worst performance.

But still I am not comfortable telling them this since I am still new to this area (less than a month), so I wonder, is there are any situation where using NoSQL in a single machine for a datawarehouse would be justifiable performance wise? Or is it just a plain bad idea?

Comment: There is no such thing as NoSQL. There are only lots of new database technologies which all work completely different and don't have anything more in common with each other than what they also have in common with SQL.

Comment: I am perfectly aware of what NoSQL means, but from what I've seen, focus on distributed systems and scalability seems pretty common feature them with the exception of some Graph Databases. I want to know if there would be any of those databases described as Not Only SQL that could provide a better performance in the environment I described.

Comment: The environment doesn't matter that much. What matters is the structure of the data. Maybe it would fit much better into a document database, a key/value store or a graph database, but it could also be an ideal fit for a relational database like the one it is in right now.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question, like the answer to so many questions, is "it depends."

Ignoring the commentary on the question, I think there may be legitimacy to your client's question. Both relational and non-relational databases ultimately hold data in key-value tuples, with indexes and such to ensure quick and speedy access to the data. The difference is that SQL/relational databases contain an incredible amount of overhead to attempt the optimal way to retrieve results given an unknown set of queries, as well as ensure stable concurrency.  This overhead is both computationally expensive and rarely results in the optimal solution. As a result, SQL databases often perform significantly slower for simple repetitive queries.

No-sql databases, on the other hand, are more of a "bare-bones" database, relying on programmers and intelligent design to achieve success. They are optimized to retrieve a value for a given key very quickly, often sub-millisecond.  As a result, increased up front investment in the design results in superior and near-optimal performance.  It will be necessary to determine the cost-benefit of doing this up-front design, but it is all but guaranteed that the no-sql approach will perform better regardless of the number of machines involved (in fact, SQL databases are very difficult or impossible to cluster together and is one of the main reasons why NoSql was developed).

Eventually we will see relational-like solutions implemented on a no-sql platform. In fact, Mongo, Elasticsearch, and Couchbase (probably others) already have SQL-like query functionality.  But right now, you are faced with this dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

For a single machine if the load is write heavy e.g. your logging a lot of events you could do for cassandra. Also a good alternative is hbase but its heavy and not suggested for single node. If they expose api in json you could look into document based dbs such as couchbase, mongo db. If you have an idea about the load then selecting a nosql data store is much easier

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a position where you need to pick one, I think you should look first at [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/). If you've never tried it, I really recommend you visit their live demo with tutorial and give it a try. If you like, download and follow the installation guide on their site. It's free, runs well on a single machine, and is incredibly easy to use.

In addition to MongoDB, I've used Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, SQLite, and HBase. I understand Cassandra should be in the list but I've not tried it. With MongoDB, I was fully deployed and executing reads and writes from an application in like two hours. I attribute most of that to their website's clear and concise instructional content. The biggest learning curve was figuring out how the queries work for things like updating a record or deleting a record without deleting the entire set of similar records.

Regarding NoSQL vs RDBMS, some points to consider:

- Adding a new column to RDBMS table can lock the database in or degrade performance in another
- MongoDB is schema-less so adding a new field, does not effect old documents and will be instant (think how flexible that really is - throw any dimension of data into this system without maintenance overhead)
- You're less likely to require a DBA to solve your schema problems when an application changes
- I think problems related to table size are irrelevant, so you won't run into a scaling problem - just a disk space problem on single machine